# Loading inherited objects with YAML C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, yaml, yaml-cpp

I have some inherited classes:

```
struct BasicShape;

struct Circle : BasicShape;
struct NGon : BasicShape;
struct Star : NGon;
struct Triangle : NGon;
```

... and YAML file which contains the lines:

```
shapes:
  small_circle: [circle, 5]
  big_circle: [circle, 8]
  star7: [ngon, 7, 3]
```

... which, obviously, represent different shapes with different options.

I'd like to convert the lines to instances of required classes. It's predictable, that I am using `BasicShape *` to handle everything I need.

Finally I ended up in writing 2 similar solutions:

*Converting shapes instantly to the `BasicShape *`:*

```
namespace YAML {
  template<> struct convert<BasicShape *> { /* code goes here */ };
}
```

That was rejected later for it does not protect from memory leak.

*Create a wrapper which delegates everything to pointer and destroy it if necessary:*

```
struct Shape {
  BasicShape * basic_shape;
  /* code goes here */
};

namespace YAML {
  template<> struct convert<Shape> { /* code goes here */ };
}
```

---

**Is there another better way to cope with the task?**

---

I have found question "[Can I read a file and construct hetereogenous objects at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27551795/can-i-read-a-file-and-construct-hetereogenous-objects-at-compile-time)" and the answer is great, but I don't need all the flexibility of answer given. I believe that the solution could be simplified in my case with or without (that's preferable) using BOOST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second solution is the right way to go about this. yaml-cpp deals with *value types* only, so if you want any sort of inheritance, you'll need to manually wrap your polymorphic type in a value type, as you've done.